# How to Apply UIAutomator API in Webdriver-io

Tags: android-uiautomator, webdriver-io

I'm trying to figure out how to apply the UiAutomator API found here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html#uia-apis in WebdriverIO. In particular how would I do something like getChildCount https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiCollection.html.